# How can I get the name of the table for any given trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm using Mysql 5.7 and I want to use triggers to set up some simple audit trail logging.  The table name the entry comes from is relevant so we'd like to capture it.  I know I can hard code the name here but I was hoping for something a little more dynamic and portable (copy and paste to another table).  Is it possible to get the table name that a given trigger is associated while inside of the trigger?

Here is the guts of my trigger...

```
BEGIN
SET @table_name = `i_want_the_table_name_for_this_trigger`;

INSERT INTO `test`.`audit_table1` (`serialNumber`, `auditTrailTableName`, `action`, `communicationDate`) VALUES (OLD.id,  @table_name, NEW.type, NEW.createdOn);

END
```

I found this answer for SQL Server...
[How to get table_name in a trigger - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335962/how-to-get-table-name-in-a-trigger-sql-server)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can get the table name dynamically from information_schema through the name of the trigger. Unfortunately, you have to hard code the trigger name into the code, so this does not really help.

Comment: ms sql server and mysql vastly differ from each other. Just because you can do a thing in one, it does not mean you can do it in the other.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow for your response.  I only meant that reference as an example of more precisely what I was hoping to be able to do.

Answer (score 3):

You Can't Do That™.

Triggers need hard coded table names.